# Why is there a delay in triggering lambda from sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a workflow.

`Function A` runs at the top of the hour, it enqueues around 400 sqs messages into standard (not FIFO) SQS queue, `Queue 1`.  The queueing process takes around 200ms.

`Function B` is set to consume `Queue 1`.  It has a small codebase (I think <3mb).   `batchSize` is set to 5 and `maximumBatchingWindow` is also set to 5.   `Function B` has a 15 second timeout and uses roughly all that time to run.

The logs show that all the queueing is done by 200ms after the hour.

**Problem:**

Logs show the first run of `Function B` isn't until around 1 minute after the hour.  The items at the 'end' of the list, the ones that got enqueued later in the big sqs dump from `Function A`, don't start until 3...4...or sometimes even 5 *minutes* after the hour.  This number is getting bigger as we add more items to the system.  This is an issue because I need ALL messages in `Queue 1` to start processing within 5-10 seconds of getting put in there.

It was my understanding that all of the messages in sqs would be consumed nearly-instantly by spinning up and consuming messages with concurrent lambdas.

Where is my understanding breaking down?  How can I get my queue to 1) start right away and 2) get consumed faster/instantly?

Comment: "It was my understanding that all of the messages in sqs would be consumed nearly-instantly by spinning up and consuming messages with concurrent lambdas." That's really not how SQS works at all. What led you to that understanding? I'm not aware of any documentation on the Lambda SQS integration that states that anything will be invoked instantly.

Comment: @MarkB - With smaller queue sizes, it is effectively instant. (within a few seconds)  I assumed this would continue.  It looks like there are "5 concurrent batches" that will happen instantly, but the rest grows at 60 lambdas per minute. ...https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-how-aws-lambda-scales-when-subscribed-to-amazon-sqs-queues/

Comment: Yes, but I don't see anything in that documentation that conflicts with the behavior you are reporting. And I don't see anything in that documentation that says anything will start immediately or instantly. At a minimum there is a 1 second delay for the batch window, and you have that set to 5 seconds. Are you saying it is not scaling up as fast as the documentation says it will? Or are you saying it is simply not as fast as you would like it to be?

Comment: Perhaps the word 'instantly' was chosen poorly; I meant 'within a few seconds' (vs 'within a few minutes)   I further made an assumption that lambdas would scale up faster than leaving us at 5 lambdas for a minute and then giving 60 more after the first minute... and 60 more after the second... and so on.
It sounds like we can increase the batch size to help and when that hit's a limit we can increase the 'reserved concurrency' to get these messages consumed more quickly.

Comment: so you found the "60 per min" limit. sqs->lamda is not the fastest option, you can play with batching size/speeding up cold start of lambda to get more from it. But if requirements are to scale it further - then worth to examine other consumer types, eg ec2

Comment: New update to Lambda SQS integration released today may be of benefit: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/aws-lambda-polling-scale-rate-sqs-event-source/ "With today’s announcement, Lambda functions that subscribe to an SQS queue can scale up to five times faster for queues that see a spike in message backlog, adding up to 300 concurrent executions per minute, and enabling faster message processing."

Answer (score 0):

By default, concurrency is not activated when you create an event source mapping between SQS and a Lambda function. To process SQS messages in parallel, you need to specify the "maximum concurrency" value while configuring the Lambda trigger.

[image]

You can set the value between 2 and 1000. Also, it's important to note that Lambda's provisional concurrency helps to initialize Lambda instances upfront, which can reduce cold start times. However, it won't facilitate processing SQS messages in parallel.